# TypeScript wiki (TypeScript-Handbook/pages/Classes.md) first example

Tags: typescript1.8

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Classes.md

I'm trying to learn TypeScript.  The first example in Classes:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

This seems straightforward, but when I log greeter: `console.log(greeter);`
instead of getting "Hello World" I get "Greeter {greeting: "world"}"

My setup:
package.json: (just TypeScript; no other libraries)

```
{
  "name": "typescript learning",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json just defaults:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typescript.notes.ts"
  ]
}
```

So, am I missing something fundamental?  Or is this just an incomplete example that shouldn't be evaluated?  Obviously I'm still quite new to TypeScript and don't have any background to take examples apart from their face value.  Many thanks for any input,
-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
let greeter = new Greeter("world");
console.log(greeter);
```

This only shows the class instance itself, and doesn't actually call a *method* on the class.

So what you want is:

```
let greeter = new Greeter("world");
console.log(greeter.greet());
```

---

To also answer your question in the comments:

> One quick question, even though the method greet is part of the class, It doesn't get evaluated by calling the class? I see this is the case, but again, not what I expected. I'm trying to get a model in my mind for using the class instead of separate function.

At its essence, a class is basically nothing more than a collection of methods and variables that logically "belong" together for some reason.

For example, if I have a class `Car`, it might have the variable `fuel` and the methods `drive()` and `refuel()`. Calling the `drive()` and `refuel()` methods would alter the variable `fuel`. This way, you can easily create one, two, or a hundred instances of one class, and still easily keep track of stuff. *Without* object-oriented-programming, all of that would be a lot harder to keep track off, especially when you start creating multiple cars.

Obviously, you don't want to immediately start `drive()` when creating a new car! There is the `constructor` method in your code, which *does* get run automatically every time a class is created. This is often useful to initialize some things, but is really nothing more than a shortcut for something like:

```
let greeter = new Greeter();
greeter.set_message("world")
```

Except that you can't forget it to use it ;-) The constructor is often used for variables that the class should always have, like the string in your example, or, in our Car example, setting the fuel to some initial level. Hence the name, it is needed to *construct* the class.

In the "real world" most classes are a bit more abstract, and there are some features which allow you to do more (like inheritance), but the basic idea is the same: a class is a collection if methods and variables that logically belong to the same "thing" or "object" − I feel some guides make this a lot more complicated than it needs to be by the way, as they immediately want to introduce concepts such as inheritance right from the start without fully explaining the basic purpose of classes.

Don't worry if you don't fully comprehend everything when you're just starting out. I think few people do. I certainly didn't. Almost everyone struggles with stuff like this at first.

Comment: Many thanks!  I thought I tried that, but I must not have since I just changed it and it works now.

Comment: One quick question, even though the method greet is part of the class, It doesn't get evaluated by calling the class?  I see this is the case, but again, not what I expected.  I'm trying to get a model in my mind for using the class instead of separate function.  Sorry for my nube'ness; I'm still trying to grasp these fundamentals.

Comment: Many thanks man!  This makes a lot more sense and also explains why a lot of my code wasn't running ;)  I appreciate very much your time and effort in replying to this.

Answer (score 0):

`greeter` is an object. So, calling `console.log(greeter);` is logging an the actual object whose `greeting` property is set to `world`.

You want to log  `greeter.greet()` in order to see "Hello, world."